# Sphere+Helix animation

Tags: plotting, animation

This is my code:

```
 curve = With[{c = ArcTan[a t]},
              r {Cos[t] Cos[c], Sin[t] Cos[c], -Sin[c]}]

Block[{r = 1, a = .2}, Show[{
   Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]}],
   ParametricPlot3D[curve, {t, -30, 30}, PlotRange -> All]}]]
```

How to animate a point as in the following example to move the line Helix:

```
Block[{r = 5, a = .6}, 
 Animate[Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3], Sphere[{0, 0, 1}]}], 
   Graphics3D[{PointSize[.05], 
     Point[{Sin[v]*Sin[v], Cos[v]*Cos[v], v/10}]}], 
   ParametricPlot3D[curve, {t, -30, 30}, PlotRange -> All], 
   Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 2}}], {v, 0, 
   20}]]
```

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always prefer to make a list of images, and use `ListAnimate` to animate them, rather than `Animate`,

```
curve[t_] := 
 With[{c = ArcTan[a t]}, r {Cos[t] Cos[c], Sin[t] Cos[c], -Sin[c]}]
Block[{r = 1, a = .2},
 sphere = Show[
   {Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]}], 
    ParametricPlot3D[curve[t], {t, -30, 30}, PlotRange -> All]}
   ];
 imglist = Table[
   Show[
    {sphere,
     Graphics3D@{Red, PointSize[Large], Sphere[curve[tt], .1]}
     }]
   , {tt, -30, 30, .1}];
 ]

ListAnimate[imglist]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the same parametric form for the point

```
Animate[
 Block[{r = 1, a = .2}, 
 Show[{Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[curve, {t, -30, 30}, PlotRange -> All],
 Graphics3D[Point[curve /. t -> t0]]}]]
, {t0, -30, 30}]
```