# How to draw a 3D point moving along a helical path?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, parametric-functions

I have an animation for a helix being drawn in 3D but I really want to have a point on there that draws the helix. I've seen similar problems on here for 2D and I tried adapting the suggestions but I wasn't able to make anything work. I think it would be really cool to see a particle moving along this path. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code is as follows:

```
 Animate[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], t/4}, {t, 0, u}, 
  ImageSize -> Small, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 8}}], {u, 0,
   30}, AnimationRate -> 3]
```

[image]

Comment: You mean something like `Epilog->{Point@{Cot[u],Sin[u],u/4}}`?

Comment: Or [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115415/58370)?

Comment: [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/187059/) may help you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a moving point using a combination of options [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html), [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html), and [`Method`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method.html) as follows:

```
Animate[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], t/4}, {t, 0, u},
      ImageSize -> Small, 
      MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, 
      Mesh -> {{u}}, 
      MeshStyle -> Red, 
      Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 8}}] /. Point -> (Sphere[#, .15] &), 
   {u, 10^-6, 30}, AnimationRate -> 3]
```

[image]\

**Note:** Used `ReplaceAll` to change the `Point` primitive to `Sphere`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

Another option suitable for convenient embedding of many graphics primitives is to use `Show` and `Graphics3D`:

```
Animate[Module[{a}, 
  Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[a = {Cos[t], Sin[t], t/4}, {t, 0, u}, 
      ImageSize -> Small, 
      PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 8}}], 

    Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[a, 0.15]}]]],

 {u, 10.^-6, 30}, AnimationRate -> 3]
```

[image]